# What excactly is a "fourier component of a density fluctuation"?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, scattering, fourier-transform, brownian-motion

Light scattering texts say depending on the scattering angle, you are seeing a certain fourier component of a density fluctuation. This density fluctuation varies sinusoidally due to Brownian motion of particles. I have a few questions to help my understanding:

**Why does Brownian motion cause sinusoidal density fluctuations?** For instance, the diagram on page 124 of this [book on light scattering and colloids](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=mmArTF5SJ9oC&lpg=PA108&dq=%22fourier%20component%22%20%22light%20scattering%22&pg=PA124#v=onepage&q&f=false), shows this pictorally, but I cant understand why the Brownian particles would ever be like that?

At any moment in time isn't the position of each particle just in a random place?

**How can I think of a "Fourier component of a density fluctuation?"** What exactly is a "Fourier component" in this context.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this has a link with the [Wiener-Kitchin Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem). It is not because at a given time, the position is random, that you can't have correlation between this position and the position at a later time. For example for a stationnary process $x(t)$, we define the autocorrelation as $C (t_{1} - t_{2}) = \left< x(t_{1}) x(t_{2}) \right>$. Note that $C$ only depends on the time-shift $t_{1} - t_{2}$. What is important is the power-spectrum of the correlation, given by $C(\omega) = \int d t C (t) e^{- i\omega t}$. Hoping it helps...